# Azure and Microsoft ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I just got my azure invitation code...yay!

Are there any official samples for windows azure + MS asp.net MVC?

I still don't get the storage providers and services that come with Azure, it's a bit confusing. I don't think MS have done a very good of explaining it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find more details in Jim Nakashima's blog: [ASP.Net MVC Projects running on Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/10/28/asp-net-mvc-projects-running-on-windows-azure.aspx) and [ASP.Net MVC on Windows Azure with Providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/11/10/asp-net-mvc-on-windows-azure-with-providers.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Just found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/11/10/asp-net-mvc-on-windows-azure-with-providers.aspx) tutorial post through Phil Haack's blog.

Answer (score 3):

A sample/walkthrough of MVC in Azure is myTodo at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mytodo  Please note that Refactoring of the myToDo sample code is required (until the sample code is updated) when the "Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 1.1 (February 2010)" and later is used. The Refactoring is described at carlosfemmer.com/?tag=/azure

Answer (score 1):

Here's another full example of a Blog and a Forum, using [ASP.NET MVC and Window Azure](http://www.azurebright.com)